# How to move WinForm window without border but with a panel covering the whole area

Tags: c#, winforms

I saw the code posted on this forum for moving the WinForm without borders but my dialog (C#) has a panel covering the whole area. I know I have to use `WndProc` to do this. I don't know what to do at this point. My window doesn't move unless I expose some of it by shrinking the size of the panel. Thank you.

The code I have:

```
protected override void WndPro(ref Message m)
{
  switch(m.Msg)
  {
   case 0x84:m.Result = new intPtr(0x2);
   return 
   }
base.wndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: If you're referring to another question, you should provide a link to it. It's not clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to give the panel the same kind of treatment, except that you return HTTRANSPARENT.  That makes it transparent to hit tests and the form will get the message.  Now it works.  Add a class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Replace your existing panel with this one.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class BackPanel : Panel {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x84) m.Result = (IntPtr)(-1);
        else base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```